# Directed acyclic graph in JSON format

Tags: python, json, r, data-structures, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to read the contents of JSON format file containing a directed acyclic graph in R. What I would like is to be able to work out the structure of the data so that I can impute it in SPSS for analysis.

Comment: Use `jsonlite` or a similar package to parse the JSON, then format it as you wish.

Comment: note that `jsonlite` is an `R` library. There will be others for python & matlab

Comment: I tried that. However because it is also a directed acyclic graph within the JSON file, jsonlite could only read the basic structure.